# Set Android Widget refresh rate via code

Tags: java, android, widget

I have a widget with a prefs activity. In that activity the user is allowed to select his refresh rate.

Does anyone know how I can change the refresh rate via code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schedule an update service to start according to the selected refresh rate using AlarmManager. Save the refresh rate to a preference. Update the widget from the service. Schedule next update from the service based on refresh rate in the preference. If the user changes the refresh rate, cancel any alarms and reschedule.

Comment: Does this mean it's not possible to do something like ".setRefreshRate(423423);" when the prefs activity exits?

Comment: If you write the method, sure. But you need to write a service and take care of starting it at the proper time.